# Converting height in centimeters to inches but cant get decimal points

Tags: android

Trying to convert centimeters to inches then round to the nearest half inch and print 1 decimal point.

```
3.1 = 3.0
3.2 = 3.0
3.3 = 3.5
3.6 = 3.5
3.8 = 4.0

float index;
float height;

index = (Math.round((height * .393701)*2))/2;

text.setText("Index: " + index);
```

When I print index it wont show the decimal. Once the number reaches .75 or higher it rounds to the next higher whole number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put an f at the end of each number.

```
(Math.round((height / 2.54f)*2f)/2f)
```

Height

```
147 / 2.54 = 57.874016 = 58
148 / 2.54 = 58.26772  = 58.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
float index;
float height;

index = (float) (Math.round((height / 2.54) * 10) / 10.0);

text.setText("Index: " + index);
```

Comment: That put a decimal point at the end but is not rounding to the nearest half inch. I started with 147 centimeters and it would it convert it increment it in .5 starting at .1 - .6 - .1 etc